# How to become a vampire and werewolf hybrid?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dawnguard

I want to become a werewolf and vampire lord hybrid. I searched it up on YouTube . One way was to become werewolf when being vampire lord and have Serena bite you again when you came out from Underforge. The other way was to have Hircine's Ring. The problem is I had already turned into a werewolf and had taken Savioir's Hide instead of Hircine's Ring. I was wondering if any of you knew a different way to become werewolf and vampire hybrid.

Answer (score 5):

It is not possible to simultaneously become both a vampire (either kind) **and** a werewolf in an unmodded game.

Becoming a Werewolf cures Vampirism, and likewise contracting Vampirism cures Lycanthropy. As such, there is no way to maintain both states simultaneously.

Comment: And naturally, it's pretty easy to find [a mod for it](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/49972/?)...

Answer (score -1):

actually there is a glith if use drink the blood during the vampire lord transformation you'll be able to do so ive also found out if you code your memory you can find your history and delete an data after any point in the game.